# In which book can I find these two topics

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, book-recommendation, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

I want to learn the following topics . In which book can I find these topics in detail

1. Derivative of a function as a linear transformation.

2.inverse and implicit function theorems

Suggestion of online materials are also appreciated
If the content is available online as PDF or video is will be more feasible .

Comment: Multivariate Calculus and Geometry in the SUMS gives a pretty detailed explanation of these topics... as well as other related topics.

Comment: Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds contains what you are looking for.

Comment: I add Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds*.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and help.